# When running my App from Android Studio can I force the emulator to the top?

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator

This is a pretty minor inconvenience, but I would like the Android Emulator to pop to the front when I start to run my app from Android Studio.

I know about the "Always on Top" setting in the emulator, but I have to minimize the emulator when I am working on my code. Running my app does not restore the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a solution to my problem - I am developing on Windows 10.

1. Create a PowerShell batch file BringProcessToFront.ps1 (*Note your emulator might have a different name like qemu-system-x86_64 *)

   ```
   if ( $args ){
      $processName = $args[0]
   }
   else{
      $processName = "qemu-system-i386"
   }

   $sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
   Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
   $hwnd = @(Get-Process $processName)[0].MainWindowHandle
   [Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4)
   ```
2. Make sure you can actually run this script from a command line. The default security will not let you run scripts, as an admin you need to allow them using [Set-Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6) 
   If everything is working (and the emulator is running) it will pop to the front.

   ```
   powershell -command C:\users\username\BringProcessToFront.ps1
   ```
3. In Android Studio create a new External Tool "BringEmulatorToFront"

   ```
   Run>Edit Configuraions
   Expand Android App and select app
   Before launch:  (Hit the green + sign to add a new external tool)
      In the "External Tools Dialog" hit the green + to create a new tool)
          Name: BringEmulatorToFront
          Description: Launch PowerShell to make sure Emulator is visible
          Program: powershell
          Arguments: -command C:\users\username\BringProcessToFront.ps1
          Working directory: C:\users\username
          *IMPORTANT*
           Uncheck the Advanced options Synchronize files and Open console
           (If you leave Open console checked your run will not terminate cleanly)
   ```
4. Run your app and watch the Emulator pop to the front!

Answer (score 2):

Following @Ves accepted answer did work but changed the batch file because it didn't work for me as it was, here is how I edited the batch file **BringProcessToFront.ps1** based on another answer https://superuser.com/questions/647216/startup-program-bring-to-foreground.

```
if ( $args ){
   $processName = $args[0]
}
else{
   $processName = "qemu-system-i386"
}

Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Tricks {
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  }
"@
sleep -sec 1
$h = (Get-Process $processName).MainWindowHandle
[void] [Tricks]::SetForegroundWindow($h)
```

Then I followed the rest of the steps from the accepted answer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AutoHotkey](https://AutoHotkey.com) for this and a very simple script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class SunAwtFrame
$+F10::
Send, +{F10}
WinActivate, Android Emulator
return
```

This runs the app and activates the last used emulator when you press F10

You can also compile this and have it run without having AutoHotkey installed.

Answer (score -1):

I have been trying to do that for some time now... I guess it can not be done.

I solved the problem by buying another monitor, and pushing the Emulator to the other one.

Comment: See my answer - figured out how to do this on windows. Must be possible on all platforms to do something similar.